# CSS grid: merge cells in every Nth row

Tags: css, css-grid

Not sure if this is possible, but I would like to have a CSS grid template where every Nth row (e.g. every third or fourth row) would merge cells into one... For example, here is a photo, what I want:

[image]

I know how to do this with `<table>` but have problem applying this to CSS grid.

Comment: you could add `.wide-cell { grid-column: 1 / -1;}` class to wide cells

Comment: What does your HTML look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way would be to use the "subgrid" feature of CSS, but it's not available in all browsers yet.

If you have a fixed number of columns however you can do the same with only CSS. Here is an example with 4 columns and every 3rd row is "spanned".

The important property to know is the "grid-column: span X"

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-column

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  gap: 1rem;
}

.item {
  background: #ccc;
}

.item:nth-child(9n) {
  grid-column: span 4;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="item">.</div>
  <div class="item">.</div>
  <div class="item">.</div>
  <div class="item">.</div>
  <div class="item">.</div>
  <div class="item">.</div>
  <div class="item">.</div>
  <div class="item">.</div>
  <div class="item">.</div>
  <div class="item">.</div>
  <div class="item">.</div>
  <div class="item">.</div>
  <div class="item">.</div>
</div>
```

Comment: That does look like a smooth solution, ty!

Comment: I'm curious how and why you would use subgrid to achieve this

Comment: `9n + 9` is redundant. Simply `9n` specifies every 9th element.

Comment: @TimR I confirm `9n` works the same

Comment: You're all right, I'll update the solution! Thx.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest a slightly different way of implementing the previous answer.

1. Use the [`repeat()` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/repeat) to declare the number of columns.
2. Use the [`:nth-child()` pseudo-class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child) to target the cell that you want to span across all columns.
3. If the grid has 5 columns and you want every third row to span all columns, target every 11th child element with [`11n`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child#example_selectors). If you wanted every fourth row, target the 16th child element with `16n`. It's the number of cells in the previous rows plus one.
4. Declare [`grid-column: 1 / -1`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-column) to span all columns regardless of the number of columns. (Won't need to be updated like a value such as `span 5`.)

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);
}

.grid div:nth-child(11n) {
  display: grid;
  grid-column: 1 / -1;
  place-content: center;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  background-color: orange;
}

.grid div {
  height: 2em;
  background-color: silver;
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<section class="grid">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div>Merged into one cell</div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div>Merged into one cell</div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div>Merged into one cell</div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</section>
```